# Exclude microseconds in rsyslog

Tags: logging, rsyslog

We're currently running rsyslog version 7.4.7. The current format in our log file is currently:

```
2017-10-19T14:06:01.123456-04:00 server-1 systemd: Created slice user-9999.slice.
```

This format includes high precision formatting (six zeros).  How do I create a template or configure rsyslog to include just three zeros:

```
2017-10-19T14:06:01.123-04:00 server-1 systemd: Created slice user-9999.slice.
```

Comment: The closest I've come to that format is this:    `$template precise,"%timegenerated:1:10:date-rfc3339% %timegenerated:12:23:date-rfc3339% %HOSTNAME% %syslogtag%%msg:::drop-last-lf%\n"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's what I got:

```
$template precise,"%timegenerated:1:23:date-rfc3339%%timegenerated:27:32:date-rfc3339% %HOSTNAME%%syslogtag%%msg:::drop-last-lf%\n"

$ActionFileDefaultTemplate precise

2017-10-19T16:11:01.749-04:00 server-1 systemd
```